# Status code: 200(iOS) from serevr , error nil but could not collect data

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, nsurlconnection, nsurlsession

after long try I could get token from and sending back as below:

```
[[UIApplication sharedApplication] setNetworkActivityIndicatorVisible:YES];

NSString *authValue = [arrTokenData valueForKey:@"Token"];

NSURLSessionConfiguration *sessionConfiguration = [NSURLSessionConfiguration defaultSessionConfiguration];
NSString *authorizationHeader = [NSString stringWithFormat: @"Bearer %@", authValue];
[sessionConfiguration setHTTPAdditionalHeaders:@{
                                                 @"Accept": @"application/json",
                                                 @"Authorization": authorizationHeader
                                                 }
 ];

NSURLSession *session = [NSURLSession sessionWithConfiguration:sessionConfiguration delegate:self delegateQueue:nil];
NSURL *url = [NSURL URLWithString:@"http://serevr.myservername.am/api/calls/getuserData"];
NSMutableURLRequest *request = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:url
                                                       cachePolicy:NSURLRequestUseProtocolCachePolicy
                                                   timeoutInterval:60.0];
[request setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];

NSURLSessionDataTask *postDataTask = [session dataTaskWithRequest:request completionHandler:^(NSData *data, NSURLResponse *response, NSError *error) {

    NSDictionary *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers|NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:nil];

    NSMutableArray *test = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

    test = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];

    NSLog(@"Data: %@", response);

}];

[postDataTask resume];
```

I'm not getting any error also status code is 200, I tried to access data

```
NSDictionary *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers|NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:nil];

        NSMutableArray *test = [[NSMutableArray alloc]init];

        test = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:kNilOptions error:&error];
```

but both are showing 0 records......

Is it my request failing but I'm not getting any error not response ....
How to access data from the server....

**My response**

```
<NSHTTPURLResponse: 0x170030540> { URL: http://serevr.myservername.am/api/calls/getuserData } { status code: 200, headers {
    "Cache-Control" = "no-cache";
    "Content-Length" = 2;
    "Content-Type" = "application/json; charset=utf-8";
    Date = "Wed, 12 Oct 2016 07:37:05 GMT";
    Expires = "-1";
    Pragma = "no-cache";
    Server = "Microsoft-IIS/8.5";
    "X-AspNet-Version" = "4.0.30319";
    "X-Powered-By" = "ASP.NET";
} }
```

**Please help me out to access data send by server**

Comment: Error checking.  Do some.

Comment: there is no error . Error is nil.

Comment: You don't do error checking when decoding the JSON.

Comment: When doing the NSJSONSerialization do the error check

Comment: `NSDictionary *jsonData = [NSJSONSerialization JSONObjectWithData:data options:NSJSONReadingMutableContainers|NSJSONReadingAllowFragments error:nil];` Use that error parameter ! Also, do `NSLog(@"JsonStr: %@", [NSString alloc] initWithData:data encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding])` and check if the value is really a JSON.

Comment: yes same error parameter shows nil..

Comment: data shows as <OS_dispatch_data: data[0x170466340] = { leaf, size = 2, buf = 0x170011090 }>

Comment: while sending NSMutableURLRequest do i have to send any thing more?

Comment: And `JsonStr` from my previous comment?

Comment: setHTTPBody what i have to send? as call go not except any parameter....